# Help with Proposition 1.13 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Proposition 1.13 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry. I just need to make sure that the following proof of one direction is correct.

I am trying to show that if a variety $Y$ in $\mathbf{A}^n$ is the zero set of a single nonconstant irreducible polynomial in $A = k[x_1,...,x_n]$, then dim$Y = n-1$.

If $f$ is irreducible, then $Z(f)$ is a variety. Notice that $I(Z(f)) = \sqrt{(f)} = (f)$ as $f$ is irreducible in $A$ a UFD yields that $f$ is prime and the radical of a prime ideal is itself. Now by Theorem 1.8A we have that the dimension of $A(Z(f))$ is equal to the transcendence degree of the quotient field $K(A(Z(f)))$ of $A(Z(f))$ over $k$. Now $A(Z(f)) = A/(f)$ which has transcendence degree $n-1$. Thus dim$A(Z(f))=n-1$ and thus dim$Z(f) = n-1$.

Is this a correct proof of one direction?

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $A/f$ does in fact have transcendence degree $n-1$? It's not hard but it's worth doing once. I seem to recall Hartshorne using the principal ideal theorem to show that $(f)$ has height $1$ and then using the nice facts about dimension and codimension for varieties, but your way is probably simpler.

Comment: I believe I do. Is it as simple as $f$ is irreducible and $k$ is algebraically closed so that it must be a polynomial of degree one. Thus $f = a_0 + a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n$ for coeffiecients $a_i \in k$. Notice then that $x_n = -(a_1x_1+...+a_{n-1}x_{n-1})/a_n$ is a root so that $A/(f) \cong k[x_1,...,x_{n-1},-(a_1x_1+...+a_{n-1}x_{n-1})/a_n] \cong k[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$.

Comment: In multivariate polynomial rings irreducible polynomials need not be linear.

Comment: I think i got it, we have that $A$ is noetherian and $f$ is clearly not a zero divisor or a unit. Thus $(f)$ has height 1 because it is clearly a minimal prime ideal containing $f$. Now height $(f)$ + dim $A/(f)$ = dim$A$. Thus dim$A/(f)=n-1$.

Comment: @MichaelN I think that's what Hartshorne has in mind, and it works whenever the two commutative algebra facts he quotes apply, but one can prove slightly more directly that the transcendence degree of $A/f$ over $k$ is $n-1$. Give it a shot! Of course, you just want to use $n-1$ of the variables somehow as a transcendence base.

Comment: @Hoot I am unsure how to start this...I can't seem to place how to use $f$ being irreducible to create a dependence relation to rule out one of the elements in our basis. I know that $(f)$ is prime and corresponds to an irreducible algebraic set, but i am not seeing how to proceed.

Comment: The irreducibility is mostly used to say that $A/f$ is a domain. I don't think you really use it after that. Just that $f$ is non-constant.

Answer (score 2):

We have to use the next proposition:

Let K a field, let B an integral domain which is a K-álgebra finitely generated, and p a prime ideal of B, then:
$$dim(B/p) + ht(p) = dim(B)$$

Now, $Y=V(f)$ is a variety, then $I(Y)=IV(f) = \sqrt{(f)}=(f)$ is a prime ideal, then, if we use the last proposition:

$$dim(Y) = dim(A(Y)) = dim(K[X_1,...,X_n]/I(Y)) = dim(K[X_1,...,X_n]/(f)) = dim(K[X_1,...,X_n]) - ht((f)) = n - ht((f))$$

Now we use the next theorem:

If A is a noetherian UFD and p is a prime ideal of A, then the following statments are equivalent:

i) ht(p)=1
ii) p is principal

So $ht((f)) = 1$, then $dim(Y) = n-ht((f))=n-1$